# Better control of views output markup?

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-views, 960.gs

I am developing a website with drupal 6, and using a 960 grid system based theme.

I want to create a dynamic thumbnail gallery with Views, and using this jquery effect:

http://www.queness.com/post/590/jquery-thumbnail-with-zooming-image-and-fading-caption-tutorial

I have some experience with views, but I am by not means an expert... I am facing two problems here:

- How to make the views html output
  conform to my 960 grid system theme
  (that means that each object in the
  views output should have a grid-x
  class, at the very least)
- How to adapt the views html output to
  the DOM required by the jquery effect I want to use.

So what I want is basically more control over the output of Views. Right now I can only get html lists or tables. Is there anyway to use a more customized DOM and put some kind of placeholders for fields in it?

Thank you for reading

O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own templates, that Views will use instead of its default ones.

In those template, you can use almost any kind of HTML markup that you possibily can imagine -- which means you'll be having a really great level of control over the output.

For more informations, you can start looking at this question and its answers : [Drupal 6: How to quickly theme a view ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77694/drupal-6-how-to-quickly-theme-a-view).

And a couple more links that might be useful :

- [Drupal 6 theme guide](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6)
- [Overriding themable output](http://drupal.org/node/341628)
- [Views help index](http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/)

Comment: Thank you, that is very useful. I am starting to get closer to what I get, but now I cannot get the output of a CCK image field. Any ideas? I get the rest of the fields with:

print $fields['title']->content; 

But:

print $fields['image_field_name']->content;

does not produce any output.   Any ideas?

Comment: I finally got it, I had to use 
<?php print $fields['image_field_name_fid']->content; ?>

I am not sure what "fid" stands for, but it works.

Thank you Pascal

Comment: Glad that you fount out :-) ;; `fid` stands for "file identifier", and probably links to the table `file` *(or `files` not sure)* ; but I can't tell you much more about that ^^