# how to Theme Catalog page in ubercart?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ubercart

I would like to change the drupal ubercart catalog page from default grid to list. Is there any shortest way?

Thanks & Regards,
Satya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is to edit the Ubercart catalog view (go to yoursite/admin/build/views).  Look for the Style option under Basic Settings, click it, and change the setting from Grid or Table to List (or theme the view; [see this page for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77694/drupal-6-how-to-quickly-theme-a-view)).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use Views+Advanced Catalog modules. It's really better alternative for "out-of-box" Ubercart catalog.

Comment: advaced Catalog module still needs to ported to D7!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Drupal/Ubercart, you can toggle between Grid and List view under admin>store>catalog

But, I recommend creating custom view which allows you to assign custom CSS classes and then target theme elements in your stylesheet. Plus, you are able to create responsive catalog pages which ubercarts 'out of box' catalog doesn't allow due to tabled display.