# Drupal 6: sorting specific date chronologically

Tags: php, drupal, sorting, date, drupal-6

I'm a drupal newbie...

I have created a block with View Module to list events (title, event date) at homepage. dates are being entered into textbox and such format as below;

> December 5-7, 2010
>
> December 4-6, 2011
>
> July 17-19, 2011
>
> ...

When I set Sort Criteria as date, it just mess :/ it doesn't sort chronological. any idea?

Appreciate helps so much!! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely your dates are sorting by alphabetical order rather than chronologically.  Install the [CCK date module](http://drupal.org/project/date), and instead of defining the event date as a text field, define two fields, one for event start date and the other for event end date.  You can still get your desired output using views (you might have to [theme the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77694/drupal-6-how-to-quickly-theme-a-view) to get exactly what you want), and you'll be able to have it sort appropriately.

Comment: so there is no way to sort the current format, I'm changing it as your advice. thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, date module is preferrable with popup submodule.

Another solution: use computed field for cck. Here add code that will convert this strings to datestamp as saveable value. So in Views you now can sort by this field.