# Get the url to flv uploaded to put in JW player of drupal front page

Tags: drupal, url, drupal-views, flv

I'm having a drupal website with a jw player in the front page. I want the url to flv file marked withe term featured, so that i can print it in the src section of player. I tried to do this views module but its giving me output with markup, i just want the url. What is the best solution for this? Is this possible with drupal views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something similar with Views. Instead of using the default 'file attachment' mechanism in drupal, I used a custom file field in CCK for a custom made content type.

Using Views, you are easily able to pull out the path (including absolutely referenced) to the file field as CCK has excellent integration with Views.

My example site - http://eyeopener.co.nz/ - which uses flowplayer rather than JW

Comment: I tried but its coming with the <div> tags and all. I also have used cck field... but dont know how to get it in front page. I'm very new to this drupal.

Comment: You will need to override the views theming template to produce the HTML required. The fields created in the views will be variables in your theming template. Hope this helps

Comment: Isn't there any way that i can get the view fields as an array so there is no html markups and all within a theme?

Comment: Yes, and my previous comment is exactly what you are after. Vies by default renders a lot of HTML, and a lot of <div>'s and <span>'s - you can override all output with theming. See another question on SO about views theming - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/77694/how-to-quickly-theme-a-view or go straight to the documentation http://views-help.doc.logrus.com/help/views/using-theme